# Upon screen lock video is paused if it doesn't have any volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, background-audio, screen-lock

In my app, audio and video play even if the screen is locked, with controls of play and pause displayed on the locked screen. However, I am surprised to observe that when the video doesn't have any volume and I lock the phone, then the video also pauses. Is it possible that **MPRemoteCommandCenter** recognizes if the video has volume or not, and accordingly it decides to pause the video?

Code snippet -

In my AppDelegate I implemented:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MPRemoteCommandCenter *rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[[rcc skipForwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipBackwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc nextTrackCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc previousTrackCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipForwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipBackwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
rcc.playCommand.enabled = YES;
rcc.pauseCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(play)];
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pause)];
}

- (void) play {
[[MyVideoController instance] play];
}

- (void) pause {
[[MyVideoController instance] pause];
}
```

in MyVideoController class

```
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
NSError *activationError = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Audio_Thumbnail_Play"]];
[songInfo setObject:title forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
[songInfo setObject:@"duration" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
[songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error: nil];
}
```